# How to style elements with/without using class name

Tags: html, css

I have given a certain section a class name- 'section-team', like that:
`<section class= 'section-team'>`. 
After that, I have been trying to style all the sections in my CSS document by using the selector `.section`,
but it seems this call does not refer to the section that was called 'section-team' anymore,
and in order to style this particular section, I have to use `.section-team`.
Is that a feature of the language or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The selector `.selection` refers to an element with the class `selection`. If you want to refer to a selection element, just use `selection { }`

Comment: @TheCodesee Yes... Thanks,, Figured it out by myself, that the coma was misplaced.. Thanks

Comment: If you want to apply styles to all `section` tags then you should use `section { }` . Keep a note that `.section` will apply styles to elements that have class name as 'section'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is for targeting class names in CSS. `.section` unlike `section` will try to find any element that has the class name `section` like:

```
<div class="section">Some Content</div>
<section class="section">Some More Content</section>
<p class="section">Some Other Content</p>
```

---

If you want to target all section elements including the one with the class name "section-team", you can do this:

```
section {
   color: #000;    
}
```

And if you want to target just the `section-team` section, you can do this:

```
.section-team {
    color: #222;
}
```